# Multiple <http> elements in Spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

Recently Spring Security has given the opportunity to configure several `<http>` elements. I'm trying to set a configuration for all the urls which maps the pattern /foo/* and another for the rest. Now I have two login pages one set in /login and the other in /foo login. So I want that all the urls which map /foo/** do the login against /foo/login.

I have created a configuration like the one below, but when I enter an url like /foo/something (which shouldn't be allowed to the anonymous user) instead of going to /foo/login it goes to /login.

The Spring Security version is **3.1.0.RC1**.
Any idea of what may be happening?

```
<sec:http auto-config="true" pattern="/foo/**" entry-point-ref="ajaxAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/foo/login" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_BASIC,ROLE_ADMIN" />
    ...
    <!-- other sec:intercepts for some /foo/* urls -->
    ...
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/foo/**" access="ROLE_BASIC" />
    
    <sec:custom-filter before="SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER" ref="basicProcessingFilter" />
    
    <sec:form-login login-page="/foo/login" authentication-failure-url="/foo/login" default-target-url="/index" always-use-default-target="true" />
    
    <sec:session-management>
        <sec:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" expired-url="/login" />
    </sec:session-management>
</sec:http>

<sec:http auto-config="true" pattern="/**" entry-point-ref="ajaxAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <!-- some sec:intercepts for some urls -->
    ...
    
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    
    <sec:custom-filter before="SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER" ref="basicProcessingFilter" />
    
    <sec:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/index" always-use-default-target="true" />
            
    <sec:session-management>
        <sec:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" expired-url="/login" />
    </sec:session-management>
</sec:http>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess. Could it be that the patterns are additive?

So the following annotation:

```
<sec:http auto-config="true" pattern="/foo/**" entry-point-ref="ajaxAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/foo/**" access="ROLE_BASIC" />
</sec:http>
```

intercepts `/foo/foo/**`. That will cause a `foo/something` request to be intercepted by your second http definition, the one with `pattern="/**"`

Comment: It was a good guess but it didn't work. I've added a sec:intercept-url with patern /** so it would intercept all the urls and the login still goes to /login instead of /foo/login. I've also tried to set the patterns inside the first http element to /login/ instead of /foo/login, but with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The `AuthenticationEntryPoint` is responsible for redirecting to the login page. You have injected a custom entry point which will override the `login-page` attribute on your `form-login` element.

Does `ajaxAuthenticationEntryPoint` redirect to `/login`?

Ideally, Spring Security should detect if you are attempting to use a custom entry point and a `login-page` and report a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Using the pattern attribute in the http element causes Spring Security 3.1 to apply that pattern to the URL before reading the rest of the inner elements, so if it doesn't match then it will ignore all the inner elements and continue to the next http element.

Does something in your log in page for /foo/login reference a resource that is covered by the /** pattern?